# Match keys of dictionary with excel columns, only matches 4 out of 6?

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

I am trying to match the `keys` of a dictionary against excel `cells`.

```
for key in dictionary_test.keys():
    os.chdir("C:\Python34")
    wb = load_workbook("Trying web.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if key == cell.value:
                print("found match")
                print(dictionary_test[key])
```

I get four matches when I run the above. While there should be 6.

I tried to check the `cell.value` against `key`s:

```
for key in dictionary_test.keys():
     print(key)
```

> Contact Person
>
> Address
>
> Phone
>
> Mobile
>
> Company
>
> Call Us

The `excel` file has the following:

> A1 = Company
>
> B1 = Mobile
>
> C1 = Phone
>
> D1 = Contact Person
>
> E1 = Call Us
>
> F1 = Address

Contact Person and Address, are not matching.

Comment: Have you checked for trailing whitespace? That would cause the == used with strings to produce False.

Comment: Thats it!. Thanks.  Now trying to figure out how to remove the whitespace from dictionary keys. Please post the trailing white soace as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing multiple lists and their items to excel cell values, if not present write the list items into new rows, correct approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850671/comparing-multiple-lists-and-their-items-to-excel-cell-values-if-not-present-wr)

Comment: Can you please stop posting what is basically the question again and again and again and again!

Answer (score 0):

Differences in trailing whitespace would cause the matching operator `==` to produce `False`.

To strip the whitespace from the dictionary keys simply use:

```
if key.strip() == cell.value.strip():
```

although if possible I would do this prior to creating the dictionary entries.